# Why does the pitch change as I tilt the glass

Tags: acoustics, glass

I noticed something recently where while I was drinking milk, when the glass was upright in my hand and I tapped the side, it produced one pitch, but while I was drinking it, and so the glass was angled, the pitch was lower. The pitch didn't seem to change with the amount of milk, but rather with the tilt of the glass. How would I explain this, and how could I manipulate it?

Comment: Well, you've learned one way to manipulate it... But, you change the wavelengths that can be 'confined' to some extent in the glass, so the pitch changes.